# how to append text to mail body in lotus notes (C API)

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I have been trying to append some text to outgoing mail from lotus notes client. For this I have registered EM_MAILSENDNOTE with EM_REG_BEFORE event. On this event, I am appending some rich text to mail body. 
But that text appears only in the sent folder mail, not at the receiving end. What I am missing?
code below referred from [this](http://www.eview.com/eview/volr6.nsf/0/60E10C63F2E130328525738B00709D51/$File/051-094%205Castell_NovDec07.pdf) document.

```
void appendRichTextToBody(NOTEHANDLE note_handle, const char *szString1) {
    #define PARA_STYLE_ID 1
    char     itemname[] = "Body";
    WORD wBuffLen; /* required buffer length */
    BYTE *rt_field; /* allocated rich-text field */
    BYTE *buff_ptr; /* position in allocated memory */
    CDPABDEFINITION pabdef; /* rich-text paragraph style */
    CDPARAGRAPH para; /* rich-text paragraph header */
    CDPABREFERENCE ref; /* rich-text style reference */
    CDTEXT cdtext; /* rich-text text header */
    WORD wString1Len = strlen( szString1 ); /* Length of actual string */
    WORD wString1BufLen = wString1Len + (wString1Len%2);

    FONTIDFIELDS *pFontID; /* font definitions in text header */
    DWORD rt_size; /* size of rich-text field */
    STATUS error = NOERROR; /* return code from API calls */

    wBuffLen = ODSLength( _CDPABDEFINITION ) +
        ODSLength( _CDPARAGRAPH ) + ODSLength( _CDPABREFERENCE) +
        ODSLength(_CDTEXT) + wString1BufLen;

    rt_field = (BYTE *) malloc ( wBuffLen );
    if( rt_field == (BYTE *)NULL ) {
            return;
    }
    //* Keep a pointer to our current position in the buffer. */
    buff_ptr = rt_field;
    /* Initialize a CDPABDEFINITION structure.We use all defaults, except for centered
    justification.*/
    memset(&pabdef, 0, sizeof(CDPABDEFINITION));
    pabdef.Header.Signature = SIG_CD_PABDEFINITION;
    pabdef.Header.Length = ODSLength( _CDPABDEFINITION );
    pabdef.PABID = PARA_STYLE_ID;
    pabdef.JustifyMode = JUSTIFY_CENTER;
    pabdef.LineSpacing = DEFAULT_LINE_SPACING;

    pabdef.ParagraphSpacingBefore = DEFAULT_ABOVE_PAR_SPACING;
    pabdef.ParagraphSpacingAfter = DEFAULT_BELOW_PAR_SPACING;
    pabdef.LeftMargin = DEFAULT_LEFT_MARGIN;
    pabdef.RightMargin = DEFAULT_RIGHT_MARGIN;
    pabdef.FirstLineLeftMargin = DEFAULT_FIRST_LEFT_MARGIN;
    pabdef.Tabs = DEFAULT_TABS;
    pabdef.Tab[0] = DEFAULT_TAB_INTERVAL;
    pabdef.Flags = 0;
    pabdef.TabTypes = TAB_DEFAULT;
    pabdef.Flags2 = 0;
    /* Call ODSWriteMemory to convert the CDPABDEFINITION structure to
    Domino and Notes canonical format and write the converted structure into
    the buffer at location buff_ptr. This advances buff_ptr to the
    next byte in the buffer after the canonical format strucure.
    */
    ODSWriteMemory( &buff_ptr, _CDPABDEFINITION, &pabdef, 1 );
    /* Put a paragraph header in the field. */
    para.Header.Signature = SIG_CD_PARAGRAPH;
    para.Header.Length = (BYTE) ODSLength( _CDPARAGRAPH );

    ODSWriteMemory( &buff_ptr, _CDPARAGRAPH, &para, 1 );
    /* Add the CDTEXT record to the field. A CDTEXT record consists
    of a CDTEXT structure followed by a run of text. Initialize the
    CDTEXT structure by filling in the signature and the length.
    The CDTEXT structure also contains the font information that
    controls how Domino and Notes displays this first run of text.
        */
    cdtext.Header.Signature = SIG_CD_TEXT;
    cdtext.Header.Length = ODSLength( _CDTEXT ) + wString1Len ;
    pFontID = (FONTIDFIELDS *) &(cdtext.FontID);
    pFontID->Face = FONT_FACE_SWISS;
    pFontID->Attrib = ISBOLD;
    pFontID->Color = NOTES_COLOR_BLUE;
    pFontID->PointSize = 24;
    ODSWriteMemory( &buff_ptr, _CDTEXT, &cdtext, 1 );
    /* Write the actual characters of this first text run to the buffer.
    Since the run of text may contian embedded null characters, use
    memcpy, not strcpy. No need to terminate the run of text with a
    null because the Header.Length member of the CDTEXT structure
    specifies the length explicitly. Only copy the null if the
    number of characters is odd.
    */
    memcpy( (char *)buff_ptr, szString1, wString1BufLen );
    /* Advance the pointer to the next even-byte boundary */
    buff_ptr += wString1BufLen;
    rt_size = (DWORD)(buff_ptr - rt_field);
    if (error = NSFItemAppend( note_handle, 0, itemname, (WORD) strlen(itemname), TYPE_COMPOSITE, rt_field, rt_size ) ){
            Log("%s: NSFItemAppend failed\n", __FUNCTION__);
            return;
    }
    free( rt_field );
}
```

EDIT1:

Code to register event handler:

```
error = EMRegister(EM_MAILSENDNOTE, EM_REG_BEFORE,(EMHANDLER)MailSendNoteHandler, gRecursionID, &hMailSendNote);
error = EMRegister(EM_NSFNOTEUPDATEMAILBOX, EM_REG_BEFORE,(EMHANDLER)UpdateMailboxHandler, gRecursionID, &hNSFUpdateMailbox);
```

Event handler functions:

```
STATUS MailSendNoteHandler(EMRECORD FAR * pExRecord) {
    VARARG_PTR ap = pExRecord->Ap;
    DHANDLE hNote = VARARG_GET (ap, DHANDLE);
    appendRichTextToBody(hNote, " Test Rich Text EM_MAILSENDNOTE BEFORE ");
    return (EM_ERR_CONTINUE);
}

STATUS UpdateMailboxHandler(EMRECORD FAR * pExRecord) {
    VARARG_PTR ap = pExRecord->Ap;
    DHANDLE hNote = VARARG_GET (ap, DHANDLE);
    appendRichTextToBody(hNote, " Test Rich Text EM_NSFNOTEUPDATEMAILBOX BEFORE ");
    return (EM_ERR_CONTINUE);
}
```

I don't see any appended text at recipient side.
But the mail in Sent folders has both appended texts.

Comment: You need to include the code that calls this method. I imagine you are not editing the in memory document's body that is emailed.

Comment: "*But that text appears only in the sent folder mail*". Do you mean that the RT is OK in the document of the mail you have sent ?

Comment: 5 cents test: Check that it's not a config problem: send a mail with RT to the same destinator, doest he get RT?

Comment: Last idea try to make a Call notesRichTextItem.Compact before sending

Comment: @KenPespisa I have updated my question, added some more code.

Comment: @EmmanuelGleizer Yes, RT is OK in the document of the mail that I have sent. If I send a RT mail to same destinator, it is received as RT mail.

Answer (score 0):

I presume that this is a client-side EM. Most mail processing code that I'm familiar with operates on the server-side instead, by hooking EM_NSFNOTEUPDATE in the mail.box file on the server. The trick there, though, is that you must prevent the router from sending the message before you are finished processing it, so the very first thing you do is you change the status of the message to "On Hold" so the router won't even try to mail it. Then you can do your work on it, and finally release it. (Usually on the server side, this involves signalling a separate server task to do the work, as you don't want to keep a main server thread from returning from NSFNoteUpdate while the work is done.)

Even with EM_BEFORE processing, you may need to do something similar on the client side in order to accomplish this. You may at least want to add EM_BEFORE and EM_AFTER event handlers for EM_NSFNOTEUPDATE to monitor the mail.box file to determine whether those events are firing before or after the EM_MAILSENDNOTE event fires.

Comment: Yes this is client-side EM. I have updated my question it is more descriptive now. Even with EM_NSFNOTEUPDATEMAILBOX (EM_BEFORE) I see same behavior.

Comment: what @Richard says is that your mail is SENT before your code run! Thus he says change the status of the message BEFORE saving it.

Comment: EM_BEFORE should imply that it the event fires before the message is saved in mail.box. It's hard to see what may be going on here.When you enabled EM_NSFNOTEUPDATEMAILBOX, did you disable  EM_SENDNOTE? I'm wondering if the NSFNOTEUDPATEMAILBOX event is even firiing. It might be a server-only event since its purpose is to work efficiently with configurations with multiple mailX.box files, which are only possible on the srever. For client side, I had actually suggested simply EM_NSFNOTEUPDATE, with your code filtering the events to just look at updates in mail.box.

Comment: @EmmanuelGleizer I am not aware of 'status of the message' at notes client side. how to change that?

Comment: @RichardSchwartz I don't know what do you mean by disabling EM_SENDNOTE (at client side). Regarding NSFNOTEUPDATEMAILBOX, in Lotus notes preferences->Locations, I have configured 'Mail file location' to Local. So all outgoing messages are first saved in smtp.box file. I get NSFNOTEUPDATEMAILBOX, EM_BEFORE before smtp.box is updated. In my opinion this should be right place to modify note, because I am actually modifying a note which will be picked up by replicator. Regarding EM_NSFNOTEUPDATE EM_BEFORE, there is not change in behavior either.

Comment: By disabling EM_MAILSENDNOTE, I meant not registering that event.

Comment: Now that you've mentioned that it's smtp.box, not mail.box, I need to think a bit more about this. I did not realize you were talking about SMTP mail here.

Comment: Is there by any chance any anti-virus software installed on your machine that is integrated with Notes to scan outgoing SMTP mail? It will also be hooking events in smtp.box, and it might be being called first. If it takes a snapshot of the note and passes it to another process to scan, then your code comes in and makes its changes, but the last thing that happens is that the anti-virus scan finishes and replaces your modified note with the snapshot that it took, that could explain the whole thing.

Comment: No I haven't disabled EM_MAILSENDNOTE. Currently I have registered three events EM_MAILSENDNOTE, EM_NSFNOTEUPDATEMAILBOX and EM_NSFNOTEUPDATE. In all those events I try to append some RT to message body. Sent folder message contains RT appended from EM_MAILSENDNOTE, EM_NSFNOTEUPDATEMAILBOX respectively. Received mail doesn't contain the same. Regarding antivirus/scanner, no such software installed on my machine. No other extension manager is installed for client.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79514/discussion-between-prashantb-and-richard-schwartz).

Answer (score 0):

I know of Domino C API EMs that add signatures via server not client to outbound SMTP emails, so this must be possible.

EM_MAILSENDNOTE can only be used on a client.

BTW If this does not make sense here, its because of the restrictions on this site, I cannot add a comment with more detail, I cannot add a link, I cannot add code !!!